# My echo command doesn't accept switches (echo -n or echo -e)

Tags: shell, echo

I have an echo statement in my script as below:

```
echo -ne "Check Script";
```

I was expecting it to print

```
Check Script
```

but I am getting the below output

```
-ne Check Script
```

But when I run the same script on some other machine I get the expected output.
What could be machine specific variables or properties because of which the script is behaving differently.

Comment: The operating system, the shell, and the value of `shopt xpg_echo`.

Comment: @Mikel: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga).   Using kshell. shopt xpg_echo didn't work for me.I got error    -ksh: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the behavior of POSIX and UNIX conformant `echo`. With a UNIX conformant `echo`, you'd write:

```
echo 'Check Script\c'
```

Best is **not** to use echo but printf instead which has fewer portability issues.

```
printf %s 'Check Script'
```

Note that POSIX allows `-n` as an extension (but with unspecified behavior). `echo -e` is meant to output `-e\n`, so in that regard, `bash` and `zsh` are not POSIX conformant.

Comment: For a longer answer by M. Chazelas, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/5132 . (-: