# echo -e behavior

Tags: shell, rhel, echo

the -e switch used with echo enables it to understand escape sequences as so:

```
[root@localhost~]#  echo -e 'hello\b\bhi'
helhi
[root@localhost~]#
```

But, the escape sequences are seemingly skipped in the snippet below:

```
[root@localhost~]# echo -e 'hello\b\b'
hello
[root@localhost~]#
```

**Can anyone help understand the behavior of the above code snippet?**

When the same code snippet above, is executed in conjugation with the '-n' switch, it works! (ofcourse, with the -n behaviour where it removes the linefeed)

```
[root@localhost~]# echo -n -e 'hello\b\b'
hel[root@localhost~]#
```

Regards

Comment: Why do you think the escape sequences are skipped in the second snippet?  Are you expecting that the `\b` escape causes a backspace+delete rather than just a backspace (reposition cursor) ?

Comment: If you are on a `UNIX` certified platform, `-e` is printed as the first `echo` argument.

Comment: @schily Even on a UNIX certified platform, that's evidently a bash prompt, not an sh prompt, so all bets are off.

Comment: On `UNIX` certified platforms, even `bash` is compiled in a way that makedit behave conformant. Check `MacOS` or `Solaris`...

Comment: For the full story of `-e` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55101/5132 .

Comment: And this question is almost the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414159/5132 from 2018.

Answer (score 7):

A backspace character (`echo -e '\b'`) moves the cursor to the left, but does not change what is displayed. So `echo -e 'hello\b\b'` displays `hello`, putting the cursor at the end of the word, then moves the cursor left by two positions, and then (due to the newline added by `echo` without `-n`) moves the cursor to the beginning of the next line. This is visually indistinguishable from `echo hello`.

Watch it in action:

```
for c in h e l l o '\b' '\b' '\n'; do
  echo -e "$c"; sleep 1
done
```

P.S. Don't do this kind of experiment as root. Shooting yourself in the foot as root can hurt a lot more than on your regular account.

Comment: Also, `for c in h e l l o '\b' '\b'; do   echo -ne "$c"; sleep 1; done` should be useful to notice why `hel` is obtained in the OP last experiment.

Comment: Note that there is significant variation in the world as to what BS does at the left margin, and so the first sentence comes with qualifications in a detailed explanation.