# Ansible shell module not respecting command switch

Tags: shell, ansible, troubleshooting

So I got the following task:

```
- name: "Use echo."
  shell: echo -e "First Line\n " > "/tmp/{{ ansible_date_time.date }}_test.txt"
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: 'no'
  changed_when: 'false'
  run_once: 'yes'
```

When looking at the resulting file I get:

```
-e First Line
<newline printed properly>
```

What I want is:

```
First Line
<newline printed properly>
```

I basically tried every form of quoting, so what am I missing?

Comment: Your shell is probably dash, and dash's `echo` accepts only `-n`, not `-e` (it will process `\n` anyway)

Comment: Jup, you're right, see below answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For various historical reasons, different versions of `echo` treat their arguments differently...

```
$ bash -c 'echo -e hello'
hello
$ dash -c 'echo -e hello'
-e hello
```

Dash is Debian's and Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`, and the shell most programs escaping to the shell are likely to use. That's probably what you're hitting here.

You can avoid the incompatibilities by using `printf` instead. It's a standard tool, and has less such incompatibilities (and always processes `\n` etc.):

```
shell: printf "First Line\n " > "/tmp/{{ ansible_date_time.date }}_test.txt"
```

As for using quotes, options are processed by the utility itself, while quotes are completely a shell construct, so regardless of if you use e.g. `echo '-e'` or `echo -e`, what is seen by `echo` itself is exactly the same.

See also:

- [My echo command doesn't accept switches (echo -n or echo -e)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55101/170373)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373)

Comment: I went with the `/bin/echo` solution as it was the first answer, but I like this approach better, as it feels cleaner and you explain the exact behavior I see. I am on Debian, so this is most probably a `dash` situation. Marking your answer as the solution as it is just slightly better fit for my question than the one by @GMaster.

Comment: @Thorian93, in principle, `/bin/echo` could also treat `-e` differently, but in practice you probably have the `echo` from GNU coreutils or from Busybox, and both treat `-e` as an option. Though if you were to run `/bin/echo --version` with the coreutils echo... As for quotes, they don't do anything here, since they're a shell construct, and the options get handled in the utility itself. When `echo` gets to look at the options, the quotes aren't there any more.

Comment: A deep dive into the echo utility. And I thought printing text would be easy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround, using the binary `/bin/echo` instead of the *shell built-in* `echo` command.

```
- name: "Use echo."
  shell: /bin/echo -e "First Line\n " > "/tmp/{{ ansible_date_time.date }}_test.txt"
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: 'no'
  changed_when: 'false'
  run_once: 'yes'
```

---

Here's the explanation regarding shell built-in echo command:

```
$ which echo
echo: shell built-in command

$ ls -l /bin/echo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39256 Sep  5  2019 /bin/echo
```

And this is the package that provides the `/bin/echo` binary:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/echo  # Ubuntu/Debian distro
coreutils: /bin/echo
```

Comment: I used this fix, as your answer was quite fast. But i think I will migrate to using `printf` as it feels cleaner. But thank you for your quick an well explained answer!